# Get deleted users details if userid refrence to some table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm bit confused with this problem, I have following table called **Member** and its structure as follows,

```
+----------+------+-------------+
| MemberID | Name | ActiveState |
+----------+------+-------------+
| 1        | PAUL | 1           |
+----------+------+-------------+
| 2        | JHON | 1           |
+----------+------+-------------+
| 3        | AMBE | 0           |
+----------+------+-------------+
| 4        | NISH | 1           |
+----------+------+-------------+
```

And I have another table called **ServiceProvided**. and its structure as follows. All the member provided data will be saved in this table.

```
+--------------+-------------+------------+
| ServiceProID | Fkserviceid | FkMemberID |
+--------------+-------------+------------+
| 1            | S1          | 1          |
+--------------+-------------+------------+
| 2            | S2          | 1          |
+--------------+-------------+------------+
| 3            | S1          | 2          |
+--------------+-------------+------------+
| 4            | S3          | 2          |
+--------------+-------------+------------+
```

Application can soft delete members by changing their active state to `0`. I need to get all the `ActiveState = 1`members data and need to get only if that member has provided any service in the past, should his data be retrieved even if he is deleted. How can I do it.

Expected output is,

`ActiveState = 1` and `ActiveState = 0` **members who has only provided any service in the past**

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What determines whether or not someone has performed a service in the past? The mere existence of the FkMemberID = MemberID?

Comment: @jw11432 If someone provide any service its store in `ServiceProvided` table. `FkMemberID = MemberID` ? Yes

Comment: @Serg All the `ActiveState = 1 and ActiveState = 0 members who has provided any service in the past `

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM Member m 
WHERE m.ActiveState = 1

UNION 

SELECT m.* 
FROM Member m 
INNER JOIN ServiceProvided s ON m.MemberId = s.FkMemberId 
WHERE m.ActiveState = 0;
```

The easiest way to achieve this is with UNION.

The INNER JOIN on the deleted Member query assures that you will not retrieve a Member who lacks entries in ServiceProvided.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, I need `ActiveState = 1` + `ActiveState = 0 members who has provided any service in the past`

Comment: Content updated to meet your clarifications.  If this meets your needs, please mark this as answered to help others with similar questions.